# How can I set max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots in application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Kafka + Spring, my doubt is how can I set this config `max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots` in **application.yml**

Because I've been receiving this message in logs:

```
[Consumer clientId=client-valid-0, groupId=valid-group] Node 11103 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1130053497, epoch=425): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Spring Boot Documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.messaging.kafka.additional-properties

> Only a subset of the properties supported by Kafka are available directly through the KafkaProperties class. If you wish to configure the producer or consumer with additional properties that are not directly supported, use the following properties:

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    properties:
      "[prop.one]": "first"
    admin:
      properties:
        "[prop.two]": "second"
    consumer:
      properties:
        "[prop.three]": "third"
    producer:
      properties:
        "[prop.four]": "fourth"
    streams:
      properties:
        "[prop.five]": "fifth"
```

> This sets the common `prop.one` Kafka property to first (applies to producers, consumers and admins), the `prop.two` admin property to second, the `prop.three` consumer property to third, the `prop.four` producer property to fourth and the `prop.five` streams property to fifth.